# My function runs when ever my sub returns a answer

Tags: vba, function

I have a sub to hide a row that has a return of 0, but whenever I run the sub it loops until it returns and hides the row, but then jumps to my Vlookup function. It then jumps back and forth from sub and function, however we are running this on 2000 lines of data and it's bogging down the sub really hard. how do I get it to not run the function when I use the sub?

```
Sub hideEmptyRows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 6 To 2000
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11) = 0 Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next I


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

and

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
xResult = ""
For Each rng In pWorkRng
If rng = pValue Then
    xResult = xResult & "," & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
End If
Next
MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

Comment: Try `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ` at the beginning of the sub and  `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you.